# Problema com group by

Tags: mysql, group-by

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
SELECT funcionario.*, emprego.data_admissao, emprego.data_saida, emprego.data_dispensa 
FROM funcionario,emprego,empresa 
WHERE empresa.id = emprego.id_empresa
  AND funcionario.id = emprego.id_funcionario 
  AND emprego.data_admissao IS NOT NULL 
  AND empresa.id = 2 GROUP BY funcionario.id
```

Ela esta apresentando o seguinte erro:

> #1055 - Expression #28 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'carteira.emprego.data_admissao' which
>   is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Então eu adiciono o group by do 'data_admissao' e dos outros campo para não da erro:

```
SELECT funcionario.*, emprego.data_admissao, emprego.data_saida, emprego.data_dispensa 
FROM funcionario,emprego,empresa 
WHERE empresa.id = emprego.id_empresa
  AND funcionario.id = emprego.id_funcionario 
  AND emprego.data_admissao IS NOT NULL 
  AND empresa.id = 2 
GROUP BY funcionario.id, emprego.data_admissao, emprego.data_saida, emprego.data_dispensa
```

Assim ela funciona, porem eu queria que os itens ficassem agrupados pelo 'funcionario.id' e quando eu executo esta query os registros se repetem.

Eu gostaria que os registros focem agrupado pelo 'funcionario.id' somente, ao executar esta segunda query funciona, mas o 'funcionario.id' se repete.

**Update**

Removi o "*" da query só para fica fácil de mostrar o resultado aqui.

Executei:

```
SELECT funcionario.id, emprego.data_admissao, emprego.data_saida, emprego.data_dispensa FROM funcionario,emprego,empresa WHERE empresa.id = emprego.id_empresa AND funcionario.id = emprego.id_funcionario AND emprego.data_admissao IS NOT NULL AND empresa.id = 2 GROUP BY funcionario.id, emprego.data_admissao, emprego.data_saida, emprego.data_dispensa
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E se você adicionasse os registros de cada funcionário em um array?

Comment: Utilizando `INNER JOIN` também da esse erro?

Comment: Você está buscando funcionario.* e não funcionario.ID, outra coisa que deves analisar é se existem salvas mais de uma data de admissao/saida/dispensa para um mesmo funcionário.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta, vejam o resultado.

Comment: @R.Santos eu não entendi, você quer dizer no código receber tudo e separa?

Comment: @RobertodeCampos eu não tentei com inner join.

Comment: Tenta: `SELECT funcionario.id, max(emprego.data_admissao), max(emprego.data_saida), max(emprego.data_dispensa) 
FROM funcionario,emprego,empresa 
WHERE empresa.id = emprego.id_empresa
  AND funcionario.id = emprego.id_funcionario 
  AND emprego.data_admissao IS NOT NULL 
  AND empresa.id = 2 
GROUP BY funcionario.id`

Comment: @LaércioLopes funcionou cara, posta e explica a query que vou marca como a resposta da pergunta (y)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para utilizar o `group by` é necessário utilizar uma função de agregação como `count`, `max`, `min`, `sum`...

Se quer obter a ultima data de admissão, saída e dispensa agrupadas pelo ID, pode obter esses dados com a seguinte *query*:

```
SELECT funcionario.id, max(emprego.data_admissao), max(emprego.data_saida), max(emprego.data_dispensa)
FROM funcionario, emprego, empresa
WHERE empresa.id = emprego.id_empresa
AND funcionario.id = emprego.id_funcionario
AND emprego.data_admissao IS NOT NULL
AND empresa.id = 2
GROUP BY funcionario.id
```

Comment: Veja se os dados que precisa são esses mesmos retornados.

Comment: Esta certinho, muito obrigado!

Comment: Beleza então! (Y).

Answer (score 0):

Meu amigo, esse erro ocorre por conta da variável do MySQL "sql mode", por ela possuir valores setados em seu conteúdo, pode ser que algum desses valores esteja criando uma espécie de bloqueio para as suas queries.
para solucionar esse erro você pode utilizar antes de iniciar a sua consulta SQL o seguinte código abaixo:

```
SET sql_mode='';
SELECT sua querie...
```

Isso vai desabilitar o sql mode em cada consulta que você for realizar. Enfrentei esse problema e resolvi dessa maneira.